# Анализатор логов squid

Tags: squid, логирование

Знаю что мне на руткод, но там админы молчат зайти не могу.
Подскажите какой использовать анализатор логов squid, чтобы была возможность смотреть адекватную статистику. На пример есть vkontakte.ru, cs.vkontakte.ru, 112.vkontakte.ru и тд.
Типа ссылки, субдомены... чтобы это все не показывало а выводило 1 сайт vkontakte.ru и группировало статистику.

Спасибо.

Comment: awk не подойдёт? Ну или perl/python и т.д.

Comment: хотелось бы обойтись средствами анализатора

Comment: А какой анализатор используется? а то их много на самом-то деле.

Comment: в вопросе написано: "Подскажите какой использовать анализатор..."

Comment: Никакой - такого решения нет - придется или допиливать - или писать с нуля.. как обычно получается когда хочешь чего то уникального..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вычитал что в последних версиях sarg, сделали такую функцию.... но только тех доменов которые ты укажешь в конфиге, так скажем полуавтомат)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри Screen squid, вроде умеет.

http://comp.ydoma.info/screen-squid-analizato-logo-proksi-servera-squid3.html